# C++ returning an array of objects from a class method

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I am trying to return a two dimensional array of 'room' objects as a kind of print/display of what's in the array.

```
Room* m_map[10][10];
```

generated like so:

```
//Initialise array to NULL
for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<10;y++)
        m_map[x][y] = NULL;
}

for(int n=0; n<10; n++)
{       
    for(int ran=0; ran<3; ran++)
    {
        int r_n = rand() % 10 ;

        Room* r = new Room(n, "Normal", true, false, false, true);
        m_map[r_n][n] = r;
    }       

}
```

So what this gives is a scatter of Rooms in the array.

I'd then like to display/print for the user where these rooms are, in reference to the NULL.

So I could for example if NULL display '#', if it's a Room Leave a ' '.

I'm unsure of the bit I should return in the method.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would really be appreciated

Comment: You simply cannot return arrays from functions or pass arrays to functions.  Arrays will degrade to a pointer to the first element in these situations.

Comment: It isn't clear how the function is related to this print/display you mention. Could you clarify that? Also, is this function a member function of some class that contains the array?

Comment: Using C-style arrays in C++ is kind of missing the point of C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza I have appended the question to clarify what I am trying to do

Answer (score 7):

It would be easier to use an `std::array<Room, N>` if the array is fixed size (and the size is known at compile time), or an `std::vector<Room>` if it isn't.

```
#include <array> // or <tr1/array> if no C++11

std::array<Room, TheSize> returnArray() const
{
    return m_map;
}
```

Be careful though, depending on the use-case, you *might* want to return a reference, not a copy:

```
const std::array<Room, TheSize>& returnArray() const
{
    return m_map;
}
```

That said, if all you want to do is print some objects, then don't expose implementation details such as the array. You can either provide a print function ot, better still, override `std::ostream& operator<<` for your type.

```
// inside your class declaration:
friend 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MyClassWithRooms& r)
{
  // loop over r.m_map and print to o
}
```

**Edit** If the array is 2D (as mentioned in comments) then there are options: a nested array structure (`std::array<std::array<T,N>,M>`, or a "flat" `N*M` array, and some careful playing with indices).

**Edit 2**: If you need to store things that can be either set or not, you could use arrays or vectors of `std::unique_ptr<Room>` instead of plain old `Room`s of raw `Room*`. Another option is simply to use a 2D map, an `std::map<int, std::map<int, Room>>`.

Comment: It would be better not to expose it at all. But provide a print method.

Comment: It's a two dimensional array that I'm returning, as a 10 x 10 grid... how do I use that? Sorry I didn't say that earlier I will edit the post.

Comment: @Springfox the same applies, you can nest the structures (array or arrays or vector of vectors, or use a flat 1D array, see edit).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is to use a `std::vector< Room >` for your array.  That way you don't have to worry about memory management, and the size is built into the array.